# cakephp multilanguage website seo

Tags: cakephp, seo

In here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp it is written

> It’s a good idea to serve up public content available in multiple
>   languages from a unique URL - this makes it easy for users (and search
>   engines) to find what they’re looking for in the language they are
>   expecting.

Suppose I have a website created in that way, in English and Russian. The default language is English, so when I open `example.com`, it is in English. And if I click on Russian link, the page is being reloaded (the session variable `Config.language` is being set to `rus`) and the same page `example.com` becomes Russian. So, suppose, SE crawls my website and has the same page `example.com` with content in 2 different languages.

**Question 1**

Does not this sound bed in terms of SEO, and do SEs have some penalties for these kind of things - the same url with multiple contents available ?

Now I search something in Russian and google shows me `example.com` with the Russian title and meta description (or some text from the page)- so I click on that link, but because session is not set to Russian I will see English content.

**Question 2**

Is not it a bed practice after all, because it will be tricky for the users, as they click on something and see something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's bad practice to have the same URL load different content.

The common practice that I've seen is to use a language prefix.  For example:

```
example.com/eng/articles/article123
example.com/rus/articles/article123
```

or

```
example.com/en/articles/article123
example.com/ru/articles/article123
```

Then, in your AppController, you can detect the prefix (after setting up in your routes), and set which language you'd like to use based on that prefix.

You can use different slugs as well, but from what I've read, most sites that are English default use English slugs for both - especially if the other languages use characters that aren't URL-friendly.

**Edit:**

Per James' point below, using a subdomain would be fine too.

Comment: ...or fr.example.com, ru.example.com, etc. Personally I enjoy that process as it doesn't imply languages are just a subdirectory, but something applied to the root level.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah, I know the other ways of doing it, but I can not understand why it is written in cake's official website that it is a good idea, I am sure cake developers r smart, but at the same time I cant understand why they think it is a good idea. Thanks

Comment: @Davo - I think you misread.  I believe they're suggesting you use UNIQUE urls for each language (exactly like my suggestion above).  The Session part is still ideal and should be used - that way, if someone comes back to your site via simply 'example.com', you can direct them to the language they last used.  It is worded a bit strangely, but I think everyone agrees with this including the book.  But I can see how you'd read it that way.

Comment: @Dave, oo, yeah u r right :), I misread it in fact. sry about that

Comment: @Dave, lemme ask one thing, in terms of ranking, getting higher PR, is  nt it better to have example.com/fr/blabla, rather than fr.example.com/blabla, I mean isnt fr.example.com subdomain considers a different website, so if I have some backlinks to it and other to example.com, say I get PR 3 for example.com and 2 for fr.example.com. Otherwise I will have all the backlinks to example.com only. So, in that point also, isn't example.com/fr/smth better than fr.example.com/smth. thanks

Comment: An SEO expert we used (above and beyond the normal SEO I do) once told me to use the example.com/en/whatever/slug  as opposed to a subdomain ... whether he's right for sure, and even if he was, if it's STILL the case, I don't know for sure, but I agree - it makes sense IMO.